# Is it possible to recuperate data entered by user in a dynamic table

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have created a dynamic table using html+php with input like a form (this is a matrix in reality) and
  I want to know if it is possible to recuperate data entered by user in a dynamic table? This is my code:

```
<?php 
$rows = 3; // define number of rows
echo ' <form action="f.php" method="post">';
echo "<table border='1'>";
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> E".$tr." </th>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$rows;$td++){
               echo '<td><input type="number" name="etat" placeholder="nb d etat" /></td>';
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" value="Create Table">';
echo '</form>'
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you have to create form by giving row and column number because you want to create matrix:

```
$rows = 3; // define number of rows
echo ' <form action="f.php" method="post">';
echo "<table border='1'>";
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> E".$tr." </th>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$rows;$td++){
               echo '<td><input type="number" name="etat_'.$tr.'_'.$td.'" placeholder="nb d etat" /></td>';
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Table">';
echo '</form>';
```

in **f.php** fetch data :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

**It gives you output:**

```
Array
(
    [etat_1_1] => 1 //means 1st row 1st column
    [etat_1_2] => 2 //means 1st row 2nd column
    [etat_1_3] => 3 //means 1st row 3rd column
    [etat_2_1] => 4 //means 2nd row 1st column and so on...
    [etat_2_2] => 5
    [etat_2_3] => 6
    [etat_3_1] => 7
    [etat_3_2] => 8
    [etat_3_3] => 9
    [submit] => Create Table
)
```

Comment: thanks it is very helpful :)

Comment: Glad to help you.Please don't forget to upvote it...@hinata